# Modifying xlsm document using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an xlsm Excel file with macros in it already.The file is 2M big ( I guess from the many macros in there).

I just want to write to 1 cell in the file and I am using POI interface. Here is the code

```
Workbook wb;
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(
                OPCPackage.open("test.xlsm")
            );
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
            Cell c =  sheet.getRow(1).getCell(8);
            System.out.print("Sheet Name " + sheet.getSheetName());
            System.out.print("Cell is " + c.getNumericCellValue());


            c.setCellValue(4);
            FileOutputStream fileOut=new FileOutputStream("test.xlsm");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("done1");
```

It reads the value correctly and then it seems to be stuck at wb.write(fileout), never finishes. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to modfy an excel sheet that has macros in it?

Thank you

Comment: Probably the file is open for reading and that is preventing you from replacing it. I believe you'll have to close the input stream first.

Comment: I tried that but didnt make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify existing file, use `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.

```
    File file = new File("test.xlsm");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    OPCPackage.open(inputStream);
    ......
    FileOutputStream fileOut=new FileOutputStream("test.xlsm");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

For more sure, before to write the file close the `InputStream`.

Comment: Worked! although not sure whats different from my solution but it did. Thank you

Comment: @Zaw Than oo: I tried it, but got a broken file as result. Original xlsm is 130 kB, modified one is 105 kB and error message appears when I try to open it.